# SQL Query is slower using interval clause compare to in between clause

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query A with interval clause**

```
SELECT t.id, t.date
FROM   table t
WHERE  t.date > SYSDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY
ORDER  BY t.id
;
```

**Query B with in between clause**

```
SELECT t.id, t.date
FROM   table t
      WHERE t.date
      BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW() 
ORDER  BY t.id
;
```

Q) Why is that query A is much slower than query B where query logic/result is the same

Comment: That can't be right: `t.date SYSDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY` Missing some comparision operators?

Comment: *where query logic is the same* Not the same. The queries are not equivalent. The former one does not set upper searching border. Test `.. WHERE  t.date > SYSDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND t.date <= SYSDATE() ..`

Comment: @Akina may I know what do u mean by upper searching border?

Comment: @BananaTech `WHERE  t.date > SYSDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY` tells that the column value cannot be below the specifies value (i.e. it specifies only lower border). My condition tells that the column value cannot be both below the former specifies value (i.e. it specifies lower border) and above the latter specified value (i.e. specifies upper border too). Maybe "border" is not suitable term? use boundary, limit, etc..

Comment: What is the difference if I use in between clause n specify the date range in term of logic ?

Comment: @Akina or another phase is in term of logic or result is the same

Comment: *What is the difference if I use in between clause n specify the date range in term of logic ?* BETWEEN uses weak compare for both range boundaries (`x BETWEEN a AND b` is equal to `x >= a AND x <= b`) whereas separate comparings may use either strong (`>`/`<`) or weak (`>=`/`<=`) comparing for each separate boundary.

Comment: The performance of an SQL query using the interval clause and the between clause should be the same. In fact, the interval clause is an extension of the between clause, so the syntax and performance should be the same.